# mysql stored procedure login

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using mysql and have a procedure for login authentication,

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE CheckPassword (IN username CHAR(8),IN password_p VARCHAR(20), OUT yes_no char(1))
    BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = username AND password = password_p) then
        set yes_no = '0';
    ELSE
         set yes_no = '1';
    END IF;
    END;
```

But it mysql warned that having error when creatinng the procedure, it say have the error i nfor line 4, it is the line of "set yes_no = '0';"? I have try this way too,

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE CheckPassword (IN username CHAR(8),IN password_p VARCHAR(20), OUT yes_no char(1))
    BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = username AND password = password_p) then
        select '0' into yes_no;
    ELSE
         select '1' into yes_no;
    END IF;
    END;
```

Didn't work too, is that a must to use delimeter when create procedure? and can u tell me statement of calling this procedure,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the problem was that USER is a reserved word. Also, I suggest you use a function, not a procedure (you just want a value to be returned).
This function works:

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE FUNCTION CheckPassword (username VARCHAR(8), password_p VARCHAR(20))
    RETURNS BOOL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS (SELECT username FROM `USER` WHERE USER_ID = username AND password = password_p);
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
SELECT CheckPassword('a','b');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `IsUserPasswordValid`(
IN username varchar(50),
IN password_p VARCHAR(20),
      OUT yes_no int 
 )
BEGIN
      SELECT count(*) INTO yes_no
      FROM USER u
      WHERE u.USER_ID = username && u.password = password_p;         
END
```

If it returns 1 then user is valid.